# Why does optimistic locking require unique version_id for each statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, locking, optimistic-concurrency

Below is a simple and common way to implement optimistic concurrency control:

```
select (status,status,version) from t_goods where id=#{id}
update t_goods 
set status=2,version=version+1
where id=#{id} and version=#{version};
```

But why do we need to increase the version_id for each update?I thought it's ok to just have the same version_id in one session,and  guarantee it to be different from other sessions. Because those statements in the same session are serialized,so they are impossible to impact each other.Am I right?

For example,in session1/terminal1 we keep the version_id to be `1`,and in the statements of session1/termianl1 we just need to check if the version_id is `1`.If not,then it means that there are other sessions modifying the data.

Comment: i think for the best optimistic concurrency control: implemention the database needs to keep a track which session can update which version also that way a other session can't modify a other session.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Sorry but i'm not a native English speaker,and your comment seems to be in a strange grammar which is hard to understand for me.

Comment: Ok i will try again.. i think for the best optimistic concurrency control:the database needs to have a table in which the database keeps a `CONNECTION_ID()` and version,, That way a other session can't update a record which does not belong to them.

Comment: @RaymondNijland But I thought it's enough to keep distinct `CONNECTION_ID()`  for different sessions  to isolate them.What's the purpose of introducing version?

Comment: Because MySQL needs to know which versions belong to which `CONNECTION_ID()` thats why you need a version.

Comment: But in a application environment (PHP for example) it might be better to store the user id or application's session id instead of MySQL's `CONNECTION_ID()`..